# Save a ggplot2 object as ggplotly and save to disk in Linux

Tags: r, linux, ggplot2, plotly

Trying to make my first step with `plotly` in `R`.

I want to convert my `ggplot2` object to a `ggplotly` object and then save it as `html` on a `Linux` platform. I want to be able to call this R code from the command line and execute it as a script, rather than run it through `RStudio`.

I thought this would do ([from `plotly`'s manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/plotly.pdf)):

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)

ggiris <- qplot(Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
ggiris.ly <- ggplotly(ggiris)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(ggiris.ly,"ggiris.html")
```

But `ggplotly(ggiris)` throws this error:

```
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
  unable to start device PNG
In addition: Warning message:
In dev_fun(tmpPlotFile, width = deviceWidth, height = deviceHeight) :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
```

I then installed `XQuartz` to be able to `ssh -X -Y` from my `Mac` to my `linux` system.

```
ggiris.ly <- ggplotly(ggiris)
```

opens the `R Graphics` device but then

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(ggiris.ly,"~/Downloads/ggiris.html")
```

throws this error:

```
Error in htmlwidgets::saveWidget(ggiris.ly, "~/Downloads/ggiris.html") : 
  Saving a widget with selfcontained = TRUE requires pandoc. For details see:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md
```

Any idea?

BTW,
I'm using `plotly_4.5.6` and `ggplot2_2.2.1`

Comment: Thanks. I noticed and fixed it, but the error is unrelated.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: works fine with same versions on win7

Comment: Works fine on a Mac as well. The problem is specific to Linux

Comment: not a fix, but work around...create an rMarkdown object with nothing but the plot in it...you will have an interactive html document

Comment: I think the error is related to X11 (XFree86 or Xorg), which provides the tools needed to use graphical applications. Without them, Linux would still be in the command line.

Comment: You're right @bethanyP. It does require X-tunneling which Mac's terminal doesn't come equipped with. XQuartz has X-tunneling for mac but that opens an interactive window, so still not idea. Can you exemplify the rMarkdown solution?

Comment: If you create an html document in rMarkdown, then erase everything but the chunk paste your ggplot code in it the hit knit, it will make an html page. You will need to write  eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE in the r chunk header. But it should make a graph surrounded by some white space in an html document. If you want to create a title and stuff, you can do that outside of the chunk. Give it a try, if it fails post what it looks like and I will edit it!

Comment: @bethanyP, just to be clearer, my goal is to create an interactive html figure from an R code that's invoked from a command line.

Comment: No, definitely not invokable from the commandline...nothing about the post above said that you wanted to run it from the command line.  It would extrude and HTML document that is browser launchable or iFrame embeddable...but not commandline interactive...you need rStudio for Linux to make it happen

Answer (score 3):

You need to install pandoc on your system. Either run `sudo apt-get install pandoc` or ask your sysadmin to do so if you don't have root access.

Alternatively, you can save using `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(h, "test.html", selfcontained=FALSE)`

Comment: installed pandoc

Answer (score 0):

I make sure I don't have `firewall` on when `ssh -X` from my Mac to to my remote  server.

Then the code above executes with no warning. (expect for creating a blank `Rplot.pdf` file from opening an empty graphics device).